# setHiddenUntilMouseMoves doesn't actually hide the cursor

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, cursor, appkit

I'm trying to hide the cursor in the slideshow application I'm making for Mac. In order to do so I wait 3 seconds starting from the last time the mouse has moved and then I call `setHiddenUntilMouseMoves`.
Unfortunately the cursor doesn't actually disappear even though I know that the program reaches the function call through both Xcodes's debugger and a simple print call right after it.
I have also tested, if there might be some mouse movement right after the call by printing something, so I can for sure say that `setHiddenUntilMouseMoves` is actually called and that the mouse doesn't  move anymore after that, but the cursor does not disappear.

This is the code is use:

```
var mouseTimer = Timer()

override func mouseMoved(with event: NSEvent) {
    super.mouseMoved(with: event)

    print("...moved")

    mouseTimer.invalidate()
    mouseTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3.0, repeats: false) { _ in
        NSCursor.setHiddenUntilMouseMoves(true)
        print("TRIED TO HIDE CURSOR")
    }
}

override func mouseExited(with event: NSEvent) {
    mouseTimer.invalidate()
}

func hideCursorUntilItIsMoved() {
    NSCursor.setHiddenUntilMouseMoves(true)
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Do you do anything with tracking areas or cursor rects?

Comment: Well, I do use a tracking area in order to receive the mouseMoved and mouseExited events, but other than that no. How could that be an issue?

Comment: I tried your code and the arrow disappears.

Comment: That's weird. I have tried testing the code on its own, but it still doesn't hide the cursor most of the time. How are you setting up the `NSTrackingArea`. I worry that might be the problem. I'm using the following code: `NSTrackingArea(rect: diaView.bounds, options: [.mouseMoved, .mouseEnteredAndExited, .activeInActiveApp, .inVisibleRect], owner: self, userInfo: nil)`and then I add it to the `View`my `ViewController`is attached to.

Comment: I just tried the app on another Mac and surprise, the cursor disappeared just fine all the time! We compared the mouse settings and couldn't find anything that looks like it might be the cause, so I am a bit confused now.

Comment: Also seeing this issue in Sierra. Cursor hides maybe ~30% of the time